# Throwing two POCOs retrieved from EF context into a new thread task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, poco

If I create a context on the main thread to retrieve two POCOs of the same type and throw those two pocos into a new thread so that I can map the properties would this be safe to do?

```
public class ViewModelContainer
{
    private readonly IMappingService mappingService;

    public ViewModelContainer(IMappingService mappingService)
    {
       this.mappingService = mappingService;
       this.mainContext = GetNewContext();
       List<MyPoco> allMyPocos = mainContext.MyPocos.ToList();
    }

    public void MapBothPocos()
    {
       MyPoco sourcePoco = allMyPocos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSourcePoco);
       var targetPocos = allMyPocos.Where(x => x.IsTargetPoco);

      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
         foreach (var target in targetPocos)             
             this.mappingService.LinkSourceToTarget(sourcePoco, target);
      });
        ^A LOT of mapping TO DO HERE!!!
    }
}

public class MappingService : IMappingService
{
   public void LinkSourceToTarget(MyPoco source, MyPoco target)
   {  
         //THERES A FAIR AMOUNT OF LOGIC TO PREPARE THE SOURCE AND TARGET BEFORE THEY CAN BE MAPPED
         //Prepare...
         //some more prepare...

         //ok now lets map
         Mapper.Map(sourcePoco, targetPoco); //AutoMapper

   }

   //PLUS A LOT OF OTHER LOGIC WILL BE IN HERE. 
}
```

I mainly want to do this so that I can put a accurate loading progress bar on the screen. If this is the wrong way to do this, is there a way to do this so that I can put a IsBusy indicator on the screen in my app?

Comment: Does `Mapper.Map` take that much time that you want to use a ThreadPool thread just to map your POCO's?

Comment: This must be one complex POCO to take so much time!

Comment: I have a lot of pocos do this for. Lets assume it does take a while

Comment: @TMan Then you should wrap the whole thing in a task, not the single `Mapper.Map` function

Comment: Well the logic of creating the context and retrieving and the actual mapping are done in different classes. This is a very simplistic example. Unfortuatley the logic is more complicated then what I'm showing but in all this is bascially what needs to happen

Comment: Then your code example doesn't really match your RL case. You should edit your code with a reproduce that reflects the issue so we can provide a valuable answer.

Comment: A lot and a long time for one are not the same.  Need more information.

Comment: Why are you adding another abstraction layer over `Mapper`? It is already an isolated unit responsible for doing the mapping.

Comment: There's more logic to be done in that method before the actual mapping can take place

Comment: Where is your loading bar?  What is a A LOT TO DO HERE.

Comment: I really don't see how that is relevant. Anyways I assume you can't since I didn't get simple yes. I'm guessing the only way to do this is to create the context in the same thread im doing the mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @TMan The thing is, you'd want your `ViewModel` layer to be updating the UI, right? Now, when all this logic is being done inside the mapping service, you'll need to do more work in order to get this done. You could be registering to `Update` events from the `MappingService` inside your `ViewModel`, and update accordingly.

Comment: You ask if this is the right way to do it but then reply "don't see how that is relevant".

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Absolutely I understand. I know how to display and update ui. That's not the problem. I was curious if it would be safe to throw two pocos into new task thread that was from a context outside that thread

Comment: @Blam I see your point. Currently the way you see it above is the way i have my code setup. The logic you don't see is just preparing certain properties to have certain values before I can do the actual mapping. Automapper is configured to ignore certain properties

Comment: You state the objective is a progress bar or busy indicator and state you know how to update the UI but don't show how you are doing that.

Comment: @Blam First off i love you for sticking with me on this. Maybe we're going about this a wrong way. Let's assume I need to create the context on the new thread Im going to do the mapping on. Because I have different classes (3 to be exact) that need access to context, what would be the ideal way to share that context that wasn't created on the main thread?

Comment: But you state "If I create a context on the main thread".  I just don't follow.

Comment: @TMan What is this context doing that you think it would be a bad idea to spin a different task to handle the mapping?